# How to control delay for every user interaction on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm creating an iOS app for researching user experience in response time. I need to be able to control delay on each interaction user does on view components such as clicking input field for writing, radio buttons and when navigating. The delay would be same for each.

Of course I could add sleep method for each interaction but is there any proxy in which the delay could be specified nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not actually done this but....

From the "subclassing notes" section of the `UIApplication` documentation:

> The only situation where you might need to subclass UIApplication is
>   when you are implementing a custom event or action dispatching
>   mechanism. In that situation, you might override the `sendEvent:` or
>   `sendAction:to:from:forEvent:` methods to implement that mechanism.

It sounds as if you have one of the exceptional cases where this might be the right way of doing things.